# combination incrementation doesn't reset to 0 0 1 when code runs

Tags: python

I am making an incremental form of printing all combinations, but after count 1 and count 2 are at 94, count 3 doesn't increase to 1 although the syntax should be correct. any advice on how count3 can increase would be greatly appreciated.
should go from 94 94 0 to 0 0 1

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from string import ascii_letters, punctuation, digits

char = list(ascii_letters + punctuation + digits)
char.append(" ")


p1 = ''
count1 = 0
p2 = ''
count2 = 0
p3 = ''
count3 = 0

combination = ''

passcode = 'aaa' 

#print(passcode)

#sleep(5)

while True:

  p1= char[count1 % 95]
  


  if count2 % 95 == 0 and count2 != 0:
    p3 = char[count3 % 95]
    count3 += 1
    


  if count1 % 95 == 0 and count1 !=0:
    p2 = char[count2 % 95]
    count2 += 1

  combination = p3+p2+p1


  #checking number count for each char position
  print(count3 % 95 ,"   ", count2 % 95,"   ", count1 % 95)

  if combination == passcode:
    break

  count1 += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the general idea right but you're adjusting your variables in the wrong order. You're updating `count3` before `count2` - but what if `count2` "rolls over" and affects the value that `count3`? Also, you're updating `count1` in a different area of the code than the other two counts, which makes the code a bit harder to read and debug. Try a layout like this psuedocode and see if it makes your error easier to spot:

```py
while True:
    # generate combination
    p1 = char[count1]
    p2 = char[count2]
    p3 = char[count3]

    # check passcode
    if combination == passcode: break

    # update counts
    count1 += 1

    if count1 rolls over:
        count2 += 1

        if count2 rolls over:
            count3 += 1

            if count3 rolls over:
                 # what do you think goes here?
```